# Deny access to specific nodes in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm quite new with drupal, and i didn't manage to find an answer in forums or searching the web with google.

I'm trying to forbid access to users of specific roles to nodes of specific content type witch are in a specific workflow state...

I manage to make the nodes disappear from wiews but using the link to the content in the navigator address bar still gives access to it.

Is there a way to really deny access instead of just make it disappear from views ?

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by "specific workflow state" ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant I use rules to automatcally publish a node it detects a modification on the workflow state on the node (selecting with the mouse in a selection list "Published" item).  I use also a rule combined with access content module (Role-based access control settings)  to only grant access to authenticated users to the node, but it seams it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Although you hide the node from views, this users can access the nodes via url.
You can use the nodeaccess module to hide its nodes.
Also you can use content_access to restric entire content types.

- https://drupal.org/project/content_access
- https://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess

I hope it's useful.

Regards.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I still use content access module, but like I said in the comment above, I don't manage to forbid access with my Rule. Maybe I'm doing something wrong... I'll ghave a loook to nodeaccess module, thank you.

Comment: Well I don't really manage to forbid access for content viewing (or just for all a content type). I'm surpised there is no a simple way to do this.. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Access content permits only to restrict access for creation/modification/deletion of a content but not for view, and node access seams to be designed only to give the possibility to grant access but not to forbid access.

Comment: Hmmm, with the Content access module you can restrict the view of any content type. I think you are doing anything wrong. Can I help you?